# How to await user input without causing program to hang

Tags: java, multithreading, user-input

I want to know what I could do to await multiple different user input keywords while allowing other parts of my program to carry on, what I have right now is a thread just listening with a Scanner, however the problem I get into is when I want multiple arguments, that can continue to be listened for until the program exits, when 1 argument is called, it stops looking for input. This is the code I'm working with at the moment:

```
new Thread(() -> {
        String in = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        switch(in) {
            case "kill":
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case "quote":
                HttpGet req = new HttpGet(BASE_URL + "venues/" + venue + "/stocks" + stock + "/quote");
                req.setHeader(new BasicHeader("X-Starfighter-Authorization", AUTH_KEY));
                try {
                    HttpResponse res = getClient().execute(req);
                    String JSONRes = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(res.getEntity().getContent()));
                    if(res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!=200) {
                        System.out.println(res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("OK");
                    }
                    System.out.println(JSONRes);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }).start();
```

Thanks for any help with my issue!

Comment: Do you mean loop ? Just put the thread code in a `while(true)` loop.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I wanted. Sorry for being dumb, it's midnight for me right now and I'm half asleep. Thanks man!

Comment: You're welcome, get some sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while(true)` loop, like @11thdimension said. This may not be the best solution, as it's a busy-wait loop, but it should work as intended.